# Converting image to numpy array in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision, scikits

I'm using Python + Scipy + Scikit-image + numpy for the first time.

I'm using [this](http://www.tp.umu.se/~nylen/pylect/advanced/image_processing/index.html) page for help, and I've only changed the given code a bit to pick up an image of my liking:

```
tree = misc.imread('C:\\Users\\app\\Pictures\\treephoto1.jpg')
type(tree)
<type 'numpy.ndarray' >
tree.shape, tree.dtype((512, 512), dtype('uint8'))
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
 type(tree) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's wrong with the syntax? I'm using python 2.7 on Windows, and all the related toolkits are also according to Python 2.7.

I need to convert the image to a 2-D numpy array so that I can use the canny edge detector with it.

Answer (score 3):

Writing without thinking may be dangerous but in your case it is just wrong. The page you've mentioned shows this:

```
>>> lena = misc.imread('lena.png')
>>> type(lena)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> lena.shape, lena.dtype
((512, 512), dtype('uint8'))
```

`>>>` is Python's interactive console prompt string. It is there were commands go.

`<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and `((512, 512), dtype('uint8'))` are **results** of commands. So your corresponding code should be only

```
tree = misc.imread('C:\\Users\\app\\Pictures\\treephoto1.jpg')
type(tree)
tree.shape, tree.dtype
```

Notice that

```
type(tree)
tree.shape, tree.dtype
```

do nothing and just show you information about your image data.

**Update**

Basically (not always) your image is layered. RGB is three separate layers. So if your filtering isn't aware of it you'll have to separate layers yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see! Thanks. Okay I think I missed out an important word in the question, I'm editing it now. I want the numpy array to be 2D. I learned that images are by default 2-D arrays, but when I run "edges = filter.canny(tree)", it gives me an error saying that the input image must be a 2-D array.

Comment: Alright I just found out! I can convert it to a grayscale image to turn it into a 2D array. I did this: graytree = color.rgb2gray(tree). Just a side question: are most image processing algorithms carried out on grayed images?